# How to Integrate WPF Application with OUTLOOK Calendar?

Tags: wpf

How to integrate with OUTLOOK calendar in bidirection way?. I should send task to the outlook as well retrieve calendar task from outlook calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The really short answer is to use the Web Services provided by the Exchange Server.